# Lightweight library cappable of suggesting different spellings of words from a bounded set?

Tags: java, search-suggestion, misspelling

I was looking for lightweight library that'd allow me to feed it a bunch of words, and then ask it whether a given word would have any close matches.z

I'm not particularly concerned with the underlying algorithm (I reckon a simple hamming distance algorithm would probably suffice, were I to undertake the task myself).

I'm just in the development of a small language and I found it nifty to make suggestions to the user when an "Undefined class" error is detected (lots of times it's just a misspelled word). I don't want to lose much time on the issue though.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Levenshtein distance is a common way of handling it. Just add all the words to a list and then brute-force iterate over it and return the smallest distance. Here's one library with a Levenschtein function: http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html

If you have a large number of words and you want it to run fast, then you'd have to use ngrams. Spilt each word into bigrams and then add (bigram, word) to a map. Use the map to look up the bigrams in the target word, and then iterate through the candidates. That's probably more work than you want to do, though.

Comment: Speed is not an issue, I bet there aren't going to be at any time more than 2-3 words to search for, and at max something like 20-30. It will always be instant.

Answer (score 1):

not necessarily a library but i think [this article](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) may be really helpful.  it mostly describes the general workings of how a spelling corrector works in python, but also has a link for a java implementation which you may use if that is what you are looking for specifically (note that I haven't specifically used the java one before)